# Dendrograms using clustergram vs traditional ways in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dendrogram

By comparing the dendrograms produced by the **clustergram** object and the "manual" approach i.e. **pdist** -> **linkage** -> **dendrogram** I found they are different, but cannot find an explanation for that difference.
Clustergram documentation says that the default distance used is **'Euclidean'** and the default linkage method is **'Average'**, same parameters I used for **pdist** and **linkage** functions.
I thought it might be related to the **standardization** performed by **clustergram**, so I used z-score for standardizing first my matrix and then each column separately, but the dendrograms are still different as compared with the one produced by **clustergram**.
Can somebody explain the reason behind that difference, and how can I use the "manual" approach for getting the same dendrogram?
Many thanks in advance.

Edit: I compared the results obtained by the "manual" approach with the **SPSS** results and they are the same.
Also, I tested all different **' data processing'** options with **clustergram** but the dendrogram keeps being different.

Answer (score 1):

pdist -> linkage -> dendrogram is also used in clustergram, just open the clustergram code:

```
dist = pdist(data, pdistArgs{:});
Z = linkage(dist, linkageArgs);

...

[lineH, T, Perm] = dendrogram(Z,0,dendroArgs{:},'Orientation', dendroLoc);
```

So the only difference can be in data preprocessing or parameters for pdist/linkage/dendrogram.
I suggest you go over the clustergram parameters one by one. You can also look through the code although it is pretty long.

Comment: Yeap I print it out 40 pages!!! I'm studying it but honestly is my first time working with a Class in Matlab, so it's kind of messy for me to follow it. I found couple of things more that can make a difference like OptimalLeafOrder, Log2 Transform Data, and the Computation of the dendogram along both directions. However the only way I can imagine for evaluating this Class is by building it up step by step... and that seems to be a huge work... So any ideas are very much welcome.

Comment: @Diego Make sure you are clustering only by rows/columns, not by both (default is by both).

Comment: Yes, I've thought about that and performed some tests: `c = clustergram(A,'Cluster','column');` and `c = clustergram(A,'Cluster','all');`. However both lines return the same "column" dendrogram and same heat map with different order in the heat map.